# Listview Adapter selected row background android

Tags: android

I am changing listviewAdapter row selected item dynamically. In the adapter by default selectedItem  is -1.

```
public static int selectedItem = -1; // no item selected by default
```

and method highlightItem is called in adapter getview method.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.catalogue_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

highlightItem(selectedItem,position,vi);
```

and here is my highlightItem method.

```
private static void highlightItem(int selectedItem,int position, View result) {

    System.out.println("selected item "+selectedItem);
    if(position == selectedItem) {

        // you can define your own color of selected item here
        ViewHolder.lyCatalogueRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(SharePreferenceController.getListViwHightlightColor()));

    } else {

        // you can define your own default selector here
        ViewHolder.lyCatalogueRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(SharePreferenceController.getListViwBackgroundColor()));

    }
}
```

When i click on listview  item

```
private OnItemClickListener itemlistener = new OnItemClickListener(){

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int item_position = position -1;

    System.out.println("selectedItemposition "+item_position);

    CatalogueEfficientAdapter.selectedItem=item_position;

    catalogueEfficientAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}
```

};

My arraylist contains three items. When I click on third item it is being highlighted. Now if i click on the second element only the second element should be highlighted but third row is being hightlighted. How to select and hightlight selected item only

**Update
the problem is highlightItem which is not updated.**

Comment: can you print values `position` and `selectedItem` in Log and post it here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.catalogue_row, null);

    if(position == selectedItem) {

        // you can define your own color of selected item here
        vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(SharePreferenceController.getListViwHightlightColor()));

    } else {

        // you can define your own default selector here
        vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(SharePreferenceController.getListViwBackgroundColor()));

    }
```

Comment: Hi,please how do you get the value of selectedItem ?

Comment: Hi! selectedItem is special separated field in Adapter

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select items manually and programmatically you can try discard from ViewHolder. 
 
determine each element in getView method!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
    // Dont decrement the position
    int item_position = position;

    System.out.println("selectedItemposition "+item_position);

    CatalogueEfficientAdapter.selectedItem=item_position;

    catalogueEfficientAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way hope this will help you...

1.define your "ListView" item selector color in colors.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="list_item_selected_bg">#FF0000</color>
</resources>

2.define drawable selector for "ListView" item
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Selected -->
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:drawable="@color/list_item_selected_bg"/>

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@color/list_item_selected_bg" />

</selector>

3.use this selector for "ListView" item selection
yourListView.setSelector(R.drawable.list_item_selector);
```